# mule esb - VM queue messages

Tags: esb, mule

When a message is sent to VM queue, how can I get all the messages that are already in that queue at that moment? I want to list all messages on the queue and get their values.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consume the messages in a VM queue one at a time with:

```
MuleMessage message = muleContext.getClient().request("vm://queueName", 0);
```

When you get a null `message`, the queue is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
        MuleMessage message = muleContext.getClient().request("vm://queueName", 0);
    } catch (MuleException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Try this one its working for me.